# HTML and CSS Issues with IE7 Navigation

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, navigation, html-lists

Im have made a navigation bar for the top of site, the final look i wanted in the end was, simple text menu but then when you hover items the background changes using a background image. I have managed to do this and in all browsers when you hover over the background changes and it is fine, but in internet explorer 7 it looks like this...

[image]

I have tried changing the heights and widths, but still cannot get IE7 to go the same as the others?

The HTML code for the navigation is

```
     <ul class="buttonleft"> 
    <li><a href="#language"><img id="topflag" src="images/flags/gb.png" alt="GB"/> English <img src="images/arrow.png" alt="GB" /></a></li> 
    <li><a href="#search">Search and Book <img src="images/arrow.png" alt="GB" /></a></li> 
    <li><a href="#offers">Latest Offers <img src="images/arrow.png" alt="GB" /></a></li> 
    </ul>
```

the CSS is

```
.buttonleft li{float:left;margin-top:-9px;display:inline;list-style:none;margin-right:6px}
.buttonleft li a{color:#D9D9D9;font:normal 13px Tahoma;text-decoration:none;height:36px;width:auto;padding:10px}
.buttonleft li a:hover{background:url(../images/topbgover.png)}
img{border:0}
#topflag{margin-right:3px;margin-left:3px}
```

Any help would be great :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a variation of your navigation and posted the demo at:

http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/HB6Zm/

I did not test it in IE7 but the two critical things to set are: use `display: block` for the `a` tag as suggested by GodFather earlier (that way the padding works on all sides) and use a strict doctype, otherwise you may see variations in quirks mode.

Since your are floating the `li` elements, they become blocks, so there is no need to change the display property.

Finally, it was not clear to me why you need a negative margin on top, but without see the final layout, it is hard to say.

I added some extra paddings and background colors to highlight the block elements and illustrate which styles control aspects of the layout.

Comment: Was aspect of my example was the most helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Change the ".buttonleft li" to display: block, and the same rule you need to set on "a" tag.
Maybe you'll need to set some padding on "a" tag.

Comment: tried these but still have the same outcome on IE7 if you want to see a live example you can view it here at http://69.65.43.221/~doctorwh/test/

Comment: Ok, I saw live on IE7, and you code is still setting the display to inline, I made a test and works right if you change the display in both tags (a and li) to block, and remove de padding of "a" tag.